# Cassandra error: Unable to find abstract-type class 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType'"

Tags: java, cassandra

I am having problems connecting to cassandra. It always tells me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to find abstract-type class 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType'
```

Here is the code: (sorta easy ;))

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().withPort(9042).addContactPoint("localhost").build();
```

I've also added all dependencies. What is wrong with Cassandra?

Comment: mario did you get any solutipn of your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from the fact that `org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType` is present only in the recently released Cassandra 2.0. What version of the driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've bumped maven dependency to 2.0.0-beta2 from 1.0.0 and it solve the problem. I'm using Cassandra 2.0.2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-beta2</version>
</dependency>
```